# Does JPA support a @OneToMany mapping between entities without a foreign key constraint in the database?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0, openjpa

This is for a legacy database.  The two database tables in this relationship don't have a foreign key constraint even though the child table column holds the PK of the parent table.

Does JPA support a @OneToMany mapping (either bidirectional or unidirectional) if the child table does not have a foreign key constraint on the appropriate column?

Comment: On this legacy code I'm using OpenJPA 1.0.1 and in order to make the OneToMany work at all I have to eager load the child entities.  I don't know if this is caused by the lack of a foreign key constraint or if openjpa 1.0.1 is just brain-dead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27040735/jpa-association-without-foreign-key/27042157

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **yes**.

Long one: does JPA actually care about foreign keys if the database already exists? If we leave the task of creating the database schema to JPA provider, it will create foreign keys, which is good.  But if the JPA works on existing database, it only cares about the existence of foreign key and primary key columns to produce proper joins. Foreign keys aren't necessary.

In fact while I worked with Hibernate we've had a legacy database using `short` type for foreign key column to point to `int` primary key on the other table. There couldn't be any foreign key, but as long as we didn't use `validate` `hbm2ddl` option, Hibernate as JPA provider was working just fine, ignoring type mismatch, not to mention the lack of foreign keys.

Comment: @org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey( name = "none") // Use this until this bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8805 is fixed.

Comment: @JonasElfström, approach with @org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey( name = "none") does not work for Hibernate 4.3.9

Comment: In addition:
In Hibernate 4.3.X annotation field with @org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey( name = "none") at lest worked for me.
But be carefull: in case of bidirectional relationships, you have to annotate **two fields** by mentionad annotation!!!