# How to disable Hibernate validation of foreign key type mismatch?

Tags: hibernate, types, foreign-keys, mismatch

I am working with an existing database. I have

```
Table A:
    b_id    int --> references B.id.

Table B:
    id      bigint
```

When I try to do a ManyToOne mapping in Class A like this:

```
Class A {
    @Id
    int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="b_id")
    B b;
}
```

I got the following error: Found: int, expected: bigint. So I guess hibernate assumes the column A.b_id should have the same type with B.id.

The hbm2ddl is set to validate because I can not modify the database.

I've come across this answer, but it doesn't work for me.
[Does JPA support a @OneToMany mapping between entities without a foreign key constraint in the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083611/does-jpa-support-a-onetomany-mapping-between-entities-without-a-foreign-key-con)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ah ha, a columnDefinition = "int" solves the problem:)

```
Class A {
    @Id
    int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="b_id", columnDefinition = "int")
    B b;
}
```